# find and replace with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a HTML like so:

```
<hmtl>
    <body>
        <h1>heading 1</h1>
        <p>blah</p>
        <h2>heading 2</h2>
        <p>blah</p>
        <h2>heading 3</h2>
        <p>blah</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to be able to return prettified text and not HTML.

I've thought the only way to do this is to find and replace each heading with the heading, plus a newline character.

Is there a better way?

Comment: have you tried `soup.prettify()`, that's what it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might insert a `<br/>` tag after each header to increase the space between the header and the content if this is what you need:

```
import re
for header in soup.find_all(name=re.compile(r'^h\d')):
    br=soup.new_tag('br')
    header.insert_after(br)
```

---

Before insertion:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup("""<hmtl>
    <body>
        <h1>heading 1</h1>
        <p>blah</p>
        <h2>heading 2</h2>
        <p>blah</p>
        <h2>heading 3</h2>
        <p>blah</p>
    </body>
</html>""", "html.parser")

from IPython.display import display, HTML
chart = HTML(str(soup))
display(chart)
```

[image]

Insert `<br/>` tag:

```
for header in soup.find_all(name=re.compile(r'^h\d')):
    br=soup.new_tag('br')
    header.insert_after(br)

chart = HTML(str(soup))
display(chart)
```

[image]